Why does menu item "Save all as har" no longer exist in chrome and what to do instead?
I just noticed that in my version of Google Chrome (130.0.6723.70) the context menu in developer tools / network no longer contains the option to "save all as har". Instead there is a "Copy all as HAR (with sensitive data)" which sounds promising, unfortunately this won't copy the actual content of the responses.

Why is this menu gone and how can I get to the full data including response content instead?

Under Network tab use the download icon to save as HAR.

According to https://issues.chromium.org/issues/361717594, the option "Save all as HAR with content" is redundant, as the option has been available for some time in the Download icon under the F12 Networks tab.
Image of the download icon of the F12 Networks tab
I've confirmed that this option does include response content also.
While I don't agree with the Chromium developers' opinion on redundancy as many people including myself used the Save all as HAR with content option, I'm glad to know this is still available albeit in a different place.

I'm facing the same issue as this makes HAR files useless for me. I'll let you know if I figure out a way around this in Edge or Chrome.
I'm now thinking that I may have to rely on Fiddler from now on. I personally use Fiddler Classic because it's free, but it's also not actively being developed anymore. They also offer their new and subscription-based Fiddler Everywhere.
Anyway, for Fiddler Classic, you can download it here:
https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic
Once you have it installed, you can configure Fiddler to decrypt HTTPS traffic following their documentation here:
https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/decrypthttps
The only down-side of Fiddler versus the Developer Tools is that it's not isolated to one browser tab, let alone one application. If you have multiple 'things' like additional browser tabs and applications open (i.e. Outlook, Teams, etc.), you're going to see requests from these other sources peppered into your network trace.

Really annoying that they removed it.
Sometimes it is really great to get the traffic from the customer to analyse errors in more details.
Hopefully they bring it back.
